# "imshowpair" matlab function alternative for octave

Tags: image, matlab, octave

Is there an "imshowpair" MATLAB function alternative in Octave?

It does not seem to be defined in Octave  image package:

```
error: 'imshowpair' undefined near line 15, column 15

The 'imshowpair' function belongs to the image package from Octave Forge
but has not yet been implemented.

Please read <https://www.octave.org/missing.html> to learn how you can
contribute missing functionality.
```

The code I’m trying to run:

```matlab
close all
clear
clc
i=imread('1.jpg');
##BW=imbinarize(i);
BW=im2bw(i);
figure;
imshow(BW);
title('Binary image')
x=input("Enter whatever u want")
cc8=bwconncomp(BW,x);
L8=labelmatrix(cc8);
RGBLabel=label2rgb(L8,'jet','k','shuffle');
figure
imshowpair(L8,RGBLabel,'montage');
title(['lable img with ',int2str(x),'connctivity']);
imwrite(RGBLabel,'label.png');
```

Comment: Octave clearly says that function is not implemented. So what's your question exactly?

Comment: @LuisMendo another function or code that do the same

Answer (score 2):

It appears that a compatible version of `imshowpair` has been implemented in the Octave Image package.  Running Octave 8.3.0 and image package v2.14.0:

```
>> pkg load image

>> which imshowpair
'imshowpair' is a function from the file C:\Octave\octave-8.3.0-w64\mingw64\share\octave\packages\image-2.14.0\imshowpair.m

>> help imshowpair
'imshowpair' is a function from the file C:\Octave\octave-8.3.0-w64\mingw64\share\octave\packages\image-2.14.0\imshowpair.m

 -- C = imshowpair (A, B)
 -- [C, RC] = imshowpair (A, RA, B, RB)
 -- C = imshowpair (..., METHOD)
 -- C = imshowpair (..., NAME, VALUE)

     Combines two images using a specified METHOD.  The smaller image
     gets padded with zeros to match the size of the bigger one.  The
     METHOD is a char array and can have one of the following values:
    <snip>

>> news image
 Summary of important user-visible changes for image 2.14.0 (2022/03/23):
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

 ** The following functions are new:

      affine                affine2d              affine3d
      imapplymatrix         imfuse                imshowpair

 ** New features "anti-aliasing" and "custum kernel" were added to imresize.
    new method "box" was also added. Inaccuracies in imresize
    bilinear interpolation and in bicubic interpolation were fixed,
    making imresize much more compatible with Matlab.
    This function now also accepts complex input images for
    Matlab compatibility.

 ** The function grayslice returns different results on input images of
    class int16. This improves Matlab compatibility.

 ** Other functions that have been changed for smaller bugfixes,
    increased Matlab compatibility, or performance:

      psf2otf               imtransform

 ** Note: In Octave versions 5 and older the installation of this image
    package version will issue several "doc_cache_create" warnings,
    regarding affine.m, affine2d.m and affine3d.m.
    Nevertheless the image package will work fine on those systems,
    except for not showing the "help" text of the mentioned functions.
    <snip>
```